# Stale ktable records when joining kstream with ktable created by kstream aggregation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to implement the event sourcing pattern with kafka streams in the following way.

I'm in a Security service and handle two use cases:

1. Register User, handling `RegisterUserCommand` should produce `UserRegisteredEvent`.
2. Change User Name, handling `ChangeUserNameCommand` should produce `UserNameChangedEvent`.

I have two topics:

1. Command Topic, `'security-command'`. Every command is keyed and the key is user's email. For example:

```
foo@bar.com:{"type": "RegisterUserCommand", "command": {"name":"Alex","email":"foo@bar.com"}}
foo@bar.com:{"type": "ChangeUserNameCommand", "command": {"email":"foo@bar.com","newName":"Alex1"}}
```

2. Event Topic, `'security-event'`. Every record is keyed by user's email:

```
foo@bar.com:{"type":"UserRegisteredEvent","event":{"email":"foo@bar.com","name":"Alex",  "version":0}}
foo@bar.com:{"type":"UserNameChangedEvent","event":{"email":"foo@bar.com","name":"Alex1","version":1}}
```

```
Kafka Streams version 2.8.0
Kafka version 2.8
```

The implementation idea can be expressed in the following topology:

```
    commandStream = builder.stream("security-command");
    eventStream = builder.stream("security-event",
                                    Consumed.with(
                                        ...,
                                        new ZeroTimestampExtractor()
                                        /*always returns 0 to get the latest version of snapshot*/));
    
    // build the snapshot to get the current state of the user.
    userSnapshots = eventStream.groupByKey()
                                .aggregate(() -> new UserSnapshot(),
                                     (key /*email*/, event, currentSnapshot) -> currentSnapshot.apply(event));
    
    // join commands with latest snapshot at the time of the join
    commandWithSnapshotStream =
                commandStream.leftJoin(
                        userSnapshots,
                        (command, snapshot) -> new CommandWithUserSnapshot(command, snapshot),
                        joinParams
                );
        
    // handle the command given the current snapshot
    resultingEventStream = commandWithSnapshotStream.flatMap((key /*email*/, commandWithSnapshot) -> {
            var newEvents = commandHandler(commandWithSnapshot.command(), commandWithSnapshot.snapshot());

            return Arrays.stream(newEvents )
                         .map(e -> new KeyValue<String, DomainEvent>(e.email(), e))
                         .toList();
            });

    // append events to events topic 
    resultingEventStream.to("security-event");
```

For this topology, I'm using `EOS exactly_once_beta`.

A more explicit version of this topology:

```
       KStream<String, Command<DomainEvent[]>> commandStream =
                builder.stream(
                        commandTopic,
                            Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new SecurityCommandSerde()));

        KStream<String, DomainEvent> eventStream =
                builder.stream(
                        eventTopic,
                        Consumed.with(
                            Serdes.String(),
                            new DomainEventSerde(),
                            new LatestRecordTimestampExtractor() /*always returns 0 to get the latest snapshot of the snapshot.*/));

        // build the snapshots ktable by aggregating all the current events for a given user.
        KTable<String, UserSnapshot> userSnapshots =
                                        eventStream.groupByKey()
                                                   .aggregate(
                                                           () -> new UserSnapshot(),
                                                           (email, event, currentSnapshot) ->   currentSnapshot.apply(event),
                                                           Materialized.with(
                                                                    Serdes.String(),
                                                                    new UserSnapshotSerde()));

        // join command stream and snapshot table to get the stream of pairs <Command, UserSnapshot>
        Joined<String, Command<DomainEvent[]>, UserSnapshot> commandWithSnapshotJoinParams =
                Joined.with(
                        Serdes.String(),
                        new SecurityCommandSerde(),
                        new UserSnapshotSerde()
                );

        KStream<String, CommandWithUserSnapshot> commandWithSnapshotStream =
                commandStream.leftJoin(
                        userSnapshots,
                        (command, snapshot) -> new CommandWithUserSnapshot(command, snapshot),
                        commandWithSnapshotJoinParams
                );

        var resultingEventStream = commandWithSnapshotStream.flatMap((key /*email*/, commandWithSnapshot) -> {

            var command = commandWithSnapshot.command();

            if (command instanceof RegisterUserCommand registerUserCommand) {
                var handler = new RegisterUserCommandHandler();
                var events = handler.handle(registerUserCommand);

                // multiple events might be produced when a command is handled.
                return Arrays.stream(events)
                             .map(e -> new KeyValue<String, DomainEvent>(e.email(), e))
                             .toList();
            }

            if (command instanceof ChangeUserNameCommand changeUserNameCommand) {
                var handler = new ChangeUserNameCommandHandler();
                var events = handler.handle(changeUserNameCommand, commandWithSnapshot.userSnapshot());

                return Arrays.stream(events)
                             .map(e -> new KeyValue<String, DomainEvent>(e.email(), e))
                             .toList();
            }

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
        });

        resultingEventStream.to(eventTopic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), new DomainEventSerde()));
```

Problems I'm getting:

1. Launching the stream app on a command topic with existing records:

```
   foo@bar.com:{"type": "RegisterUserCommand", "command": {"name":"Alex","email":"foo@bar.com"}}
   foo@bar.com:{"type": "ChangeUserNameCommand", "command": {"email":"foo@bar.com","newName":"Alex1"}}

Outcome:
   1. Stream application fails when processing the ChangeUserNameCommand, because the snapshot is null.
   2. The events topic has a record for successful registration, but nothing for changing the name:
   /*OK*/foo@bar.com:{"type":"UserRegisteredEvent","event":{"email":"foo@bar.com","name":"Alex",  "version":0}}
   
Thoughts:
   When processing the ChangeUserNameCommand, the snapshot is missing in the aggregated KTable, userSnapshots. Restarting the application succesfully produces the following record:
   foo@bar.com: {"type":"UserNameChangedEvent","event":{"email":"foo@bar.com","name":"Alex1","version":1}}
   
   Tried increasing the max.task.idle.ms to 4 seconds - no effect.
```

2. Launching the stream app and producing a set of ChangeUserNameCommand commands at a time (fast).

```
Producing:
   
   // Produce to command topic
   foo@bar.com:{"type": "RegisterUserCommand", "command": {"name":"Alex","email":"foo@bar.com"}}
   
   // event topic outcome
   /*OK*/ foo@bar.com:{"type":"UserRegisteredEvent","event":{"email":"foo@bar.com","name":"Alex",  "version":0}}
   
   // Produce at once to command topic
   foo@bar.com:{"type": "ChangeUserNameCommand", "command": {"email":"foo@bar.com","newName":"Alex1"}}
   foo@bar.com:{"type": "ChangeUserNameCommand", "command": {"email":"foo@bar.com","newName":"Alex2"}}
   foo@bar.com:{"type": "ChangeUserNameCommand", "command": {"email":"foo@bar.com","newName":"Alex3"}}
   
   // event topic outcome
   /*OK*/foo@bar.com: {"type":"UserNameChangedEvent","event":{"email":"foo@bar.com","name":"Alex1","version":1}}
   /*NOK*/foo@bar.com: {"type":"UserNameChangedEvent","event":{"email":"foo@bar.com","name":"Alex2","version":1}}
   /*NOK*/foo@bar.com: {"type":"UserNameChangedEvent","event":{"email":"foo@bar.com","name":"Alex3","version":1}}
   
Thoughts:
   'ChangeUserNameCommand' commands are joined with a stale version of snapshot (pay attention to the version attribute).
   The expected outcome would be:
   foo@bar.com: {"type":"UserNameChangedEvent","event":{"email":"foo@bar.com","name":"Alex1","version":1}}
   foo@bar.com: {"type":"UserNameChangedEvent","event":{"email":"foo@bar.com","name":"Alex2","version":2}}
   foo@bar.com: {"type":"UserNameChangedEvent","event":{"email":"foo@bar.com","name":"Alex3","version":3}}

   Tried increasing the max.task.idle.ms to 4 seconds - no effect, setting the cache_max_bytes_buffering to 0 has no effect.
```

What am I missing in building such a topology? I expect that every command to be processed on the latest version of the snapshot. If I produce the commands with a few seconds delay between them, everything works as expected.

Comment: Checked the logs, and it looks like the second command starts to be processed before the event record produced after executing the first command is fetched from partition. Not sure why. I use the max.task.idle.ms setting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed change-log recovery part for the Tables. Read [this](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-tables-part-4-elasticity-fault-tolerance-advanced-concepts/) to understand what happens with change-log recovery.

> For tables, it is more complex because they must maintain additional
> information—their state—to allow for stateful processing such as joins
> and aggregations like COUNT() or SUM(). To achieve this while also
> ensuring high processing performance, tables (through their state
> stores) are materialized on local disk within a Kafka Streams
> application instance or a ksqlDB server. But machines and containers
> can be lost, along with any locally stored data. How can we make
> tables fault tolerant, too?
>
> The answer is that any data stored in a table is also stored remotely
> in Kafka. Every table has its own change stream for this purpose—a
> built-in change data capture (CDC) setup, we could say. So if we have
> a table of account balances by customer, every time an account balance
> is updated, a corresponding change event will be recorded into the
> change stream of that table.

Also keep in mind, Restart a Kafka stream application should not process previously processed events. For that you need to commit offset of the message after processed it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause. Not sure if it is by design or a bug, but a stream task will wait only once per processing cycle for data in other partitions.
So if 2 records from command topic were read first, the stream task will wait `max.task.idle.ms`, allowing the poll() phase to happen, when processing the first command record. After it is processed, during processing the second one, the stream task will not allow polling to get newly generated events that resulted from first command processing.

In kafka 2.8, the code that is responsible for this behavior is in StreamTask.java. `IsProcessable()` is invoked at the beginning of processing phase. If it returns false, this will lead to repeating the polling phase.

```
   public boolean isProcessable(final long wallClockTime) {
        if (state() == State.CLOSED) {
            return false;
        }

        if (hasPendingTxCommit) {
            return false;
        }

        if (partitionGroup.allPartitionsBuffered()) {
            idleStartTimeMs = RecordQueue.UNKNOWN;
            return true;
        } else if (partitionGroup.numBuffered() > 0) {
            if (idleStartTimeMs == RecordQueue.UNKNOWN) {
                idleStartTimeMs = wallClockTime;
            }

            if (wallClockTime - idleStartTimeMs >= maxTaskIdleMs) {
                return true;

                // idleStartTimeMs is not reset to default, RecordQueue.UNKNOWN, value, 
                // therefore the next time when the check for all buffered partitions is done, `true` is returned, meaning that the task is ready to be processed.  
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // there's no data in any of the topics; we should reset the enforced
            // processing timer
            idleStartTimeMs = RecordQueue.UNKNOWN;
            return false;
        }
    }
```